# my react website is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, netlify

I am learning react and I created a site for exercise.
locally the site works very well but after the build on the server internet the routing no longer works correctly.
see here: https://sparkling-bubblegum-dcd572.netlify.app/
clicking on “about” works but not the refresh.
my code:
app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
        {/* path="*" fonctionne si jamais l'url ne correspond à rien de déclaré au dessus */}
        <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

navigation.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      <ul>
        <NavLink to="/" className={(nav) => (nav.isActive ? "nav-active" : "")}>
          <li>accueil</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/about"
          className={(nav) => (nav.isActive ? "nav-active" : "")}
        >
          <li>à propos</li>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          to="/blog"
          className={(nav) => (nav.isActive ? "nav-active" : "")}
        >
          <li>Blog</li>
        </NavLink>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

can you help me for this problem?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think, when you're refreshing the url https://sparkling-bubblegum-dcd572.netlify.app/about in your browser, it tries to get something like a file named `about.html` from the server. But probably there is only a file named `index.html` in the root-directory of the webserver. So you have to tell netlify, that all paths should be handled by `index.html`. How to do this may be described in the [netlify docs](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/).